# Building latest version of MUMPS 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: build, blacs

As instructed in the INSTALL file in the top directory of the tarball,
I executed

```
cp Make.inc/Makefile.debian.PAR ./Makefile.inc
```

Then I ran make. However, i ran into the following error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '../MUMPS_5.2.1/examples'
mpif90 -O -fopenmp  -I. -I../include -I../src -c dsimpletest.F -o dsimpletest.o
mpif90 -o dsimpletest -O -fopenmp dsimpletest.o  ../lib/libdmumps.a ../lib/libmumps_common.a   
-L/usr/lib  -lmetis -L../PORD/lib/ -lpord -L/usr/lib -lesmumps -lscotch -lscotcherr -lscalapack- 
openmpi -llapack  -lblas -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libdmumps.a(dend_driver.o): undefined reference to symbol 'blacs_gridexit_'
//usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'dsimpletest' failed
make[1]: *** [dsimpletest] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/.../MUMPS_5.2.1/examples'
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'dexamples' failed
make: *** [dexamples] Error 2
```

To hunt down the source of the error, i tried each of the precisions in turn

```
make s     # single precision real
make d     # double precision real
make c     # complex
make z     # double complex
```

Each of them ran to completion. It's only the examples that were not compiling
None of the following commands worked. They all failed with the same error

```
make sexamples
make dexamples
make cexamples
make zexamples
```

Common error :

```
mpif90 -o dsimpletest -O -fopenmp dsimpletest.o  ../lib/libdmumps.a ../lib/libmumps_common.a   
-L/usr/lib  -lmetis -L../PORD/lib/ -lpord -L/usr/lib -lesmumps -lscotch -lscotcherr -lscalapack- 
openmpi -llapack  -lblas -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libdmumps.a(dend_driver.o): undefined reference to symbol 'blacs_gridexit_'
//usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I installed all these packages that contain blacs, but still did not work

```
   sudo apt install libscalapack-openmpi1
   sudo apt install libscalapack-mpi-dev
   sudo apt install libblacs-mpi-dev
   sudo apt install libblacs-openmpi1
   sudo apt install blacs-mpi-test blacs-test-common
```

What to do next ?

Answer (score 0):

The examples directory inside the tarball has its own Makefile.
It imports the Makefile.inc from the toplevel directory

The original Makefile.inc

```
LIBBLAS = -lblas
LIBOTHERS = -lpthread
```

If you've installed all the blacs package above, your /usr/lib will look something like this

```
 find . -iname "*blacs*"
./libblacs-openmpi.so.1.1
./libblacsF77init-openmpi.a
./libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1
./libblacsF77init-openmpi.so.1
./blacs
./blacs/fblacs_test_shared-openmpi
./blacs/cblacs_test_shared-openmpi
./blacs/fblacs_test_static-openmpi
./blacs/cblacs_test_static-openmpi
./libblacsCinit-openmpi.a
./libblacs-openmpi.a
./libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1.1
./libblacsF77init-openmpi.so.1.1
./libblacs-openmpi.so
./libblacsF77init-openmpi.so
./libblacsCinit-openmpi.so
./libblacs-openmpi.so.1
```

Change the lines in Makefile.inc to

```
LIBBLAS   = -lblas
LIBOTHERS = -lpthread -lblacs-openmpi
```

Everything started working for me. 
The executed compiler command is now

```
mpif90 -o dsimpletest -O -fopenmp dsimpletest.o  ../lib/libdmumps.a ../lib/libmumps_common.a    
-L/usr/lib  -lmetis -L../PORD/lib/ -lpord -L/usr/lib -lesmumps -lscotch -lscotcherr -lscalapack-
openmpi -llapack  -lblas -lpthread -lblacs-openmpi
```

... as opposed to the original command without the -lblacs-openmpi linker command.

Now the examples directory contains all the built executable examples.